# Using GDAL TMS in QGIS?

Tags: qgis, tiles, tile-map-service

I'm trying to load tiles from the below server to QGIS by GDAL TMS support (like here: https://www.3liz.com/blog/rldhont/index.php?post/2012/07/17/OpenStreetMap-Tiles-in-QGIS), but it doesn't work - any hints on what's wrong with my XML?

```
<GDAL_WMS>
    <Service name="Kompass.de">
        <ServerUrl>http://ec2.cdn.ecmaps.de/WmsGateway.ashx.jpg?Experience=kompass&MapStyle=KOMPASS%20Touristik&TileX=${x}&TileY=${y}&ZoomLevel=${z}</ServerUrl>
    </Service>
    <DataWindow>
    <UpperLeftX>-20037508.34</UpperLeftX>
    <UpperLeftY>20037508.34</UpperLeftY>
    <LowerRightX>20037508.34</LowerRightX>
    <LowerRightY>-20037508.34</LowerRightY>
    <TileLevel>18</TileLevel>
    <TileCountX>1</TileCountX>
    <TileCountY>1</TileCountY>
    <YOrigin>top</YOrigin>
    </DataWindow>
    <Projection>EPSG:3857</Projection>
    <ImageFormat>image/jpeg</ImageFormat>
    <BlockSizeX>256</BlockSizeX>
    <BlockSizeY>256</BlockSizeY>
    <BandsCount>3</BandsCount>
     <Cache />
</GDAL_WMS>
```

Answer (score 1):

The service name (where you wrote `Kompass.de`) isn't your name for the service, its the kind of service (e.g. TMS or WMS).

So you need:

`<GDAL_WMS>
    <Service name="TMS">
        <ServerUrl>http://ec2.cdn.ecmaps.de/WmsGateway.ashx.jpg?Experience=kompass&MapStyle=KOMPASS%20Touristik&TileX=${x}&TileY=${y}&ZoomLevel=${z}</ServerUrl>
    </Service>
    <DataWindow>
    <UpperLeftX>-20037508.34</UpperLeftX>
    <UpperLeftY>20037508.34</UpperLeftY>
    <LowerRightX>20037508.34</LowerRightX>
    <LowerRightY>-20037508.34</LowerRightY>
    <TileLevel>18</TileLevel>
    <TileCountX>1</TileCountX>
    <TileCountY>1</TileCountY>
    <YOrigin>top</YOrigin>
    </DataWindow>
    <Projection>EPSG:3857</Projection>
    <ImageFormat>image/jpeg</ImageFormat>
    <BlockSizeX>256</BlockSizeX>
    <BlockSizeY>256</BlockSizeY>
    <BandsCount>3</BandsCount>
    <Cache />
</GDAL_WMS>`

You can test with `gdalinfo yourfile.xml` (where `yourfile.xml` is whatever you called your XML), which for me produces:

`Driver: WMS/OGC Web Map Service
Files: test.xml
Size is 67108864, 67108864
Coordinate System is:
PROJCS["WGS 84 / Pseudo-Mercator",
    GEOGCS["WGS 84",
        DATUM["WGS_1984",
            SPHEROID["WGS 84",6378137,298.257223563,
                AUTHORITY["EPSG","7030"]],
            AUTHORITY["EPSG","6326"]],
        PRIMEM["Greenwich",0,
            AUTHORITY["EPSG","8901"]],
        UNIT["degree",0.0174532925199433,
            AUTHORITY["EPSG","9122"]],
        AUTHORITY["EPSG","4326"]],
    PROJECTION["Mercator_1SP"],
    PARAMETER["central_meridian",0],
    PARAMETER["scale_factor",1],
    PARAMETER["false_easting",0],
    PARAMETER["false_northing",0],
    UNIT["metre",1,
        AUTHORITY["EPSG","9001"]],
    AXIS["X",EAST],
    AXIS["Y",NORTH],
    EXTENSION["PROJ4","+proj=merc +a=6378137 +b=6378137 +lat_ts=0.0 +lon_0=0.0 +x_0=0.0 +y_0=0 +k=1.0 +units=m +nadgrids=@null +wktext +no_defs"],
    AUTHORITY["EPSG","3857"]]
Origin = (-20037508.339999999850988,20037508.339999999850988)
Pixel Size = (0.597164283394814,-0.597164283394814)
Image Structure Metadata:
  INTERLEAVE=PIXEL
Corner Coordinates:
Upper Left  (-20037508.340,20037508.340) (180d 0' 0.00"W, 85d 3' 4.06"N)
Lower Left  (-20037508.340,-20037508.340) (180d 0' 0.00"W, 85d 3' 4.06"S)
Upper Right (20037508.340,20037508.340) (180d 0' 0.00"E, 85d 3' 4.06"N)
Lower Right (20037508.340,-20037508.340) (180d 0' 0.00"E, 85d 3' 4.06"S)
Center      (   0.0000000,   0.0000000) (  0d 0' 0.01"E,  0d 0' 0.01"N)
Band 1 Block=256x256 Type=Byte, ColorInterp=Red
  Overviews: 33554432x33554432, 16777216x16777216, 8388608x8388608, 4194304x4194304, 2097152x2097152, 1048576x1048576, 524288x524288, 262144x262144, 131072x131072, 65536x65536, 32768x32768, 16384x16384, 8192x8192, 4096x4096, 2048x2048, 1024x1024, 512x512, 256x256
Band 2 Block=256x256 Type=Byte, ColorInterp=Green
  Overviews: 33554432x33554432, 16777216x16777216, 8388608x8388608, 4194304x4194304, 2097152x2097152, 1048576x1048576, 524288x524288, 262144x262144, 131072x131072, 65536x65536, 32768x32768, 16384x16384, 8192x8192, 4096x4096, 2048x2048, 1024x1024, 512x512, 256x256
Band 3 Block=256x256 Type=Byte, ColorInterp=Blue
  Overviews: 33554432x33554432, 16777216x16777216, 8388608x8388608, 4194304x4194304, 2097152x2097152, 1048576x1048576, 524288x524288, 262144x262144, 131072x131072, 65536x65536, 32768x32768, 16384x16384, 8192x8192, 4096x4096, 2048x2048, 1024x1024, 512x512, 256x256`

Comment: I tried that, but the tiles don't show up in QGIS. Substituting the `${ }` with zeros delivers a tile in the browser, so the service is running.

Comment: Perhaps some other issue, like wrong projection.

Comment: No, it is the standard Google mercator tiling scheme. Maybe there is some kind of authentification required.

Comment: thx, i tried this, too - to no evail.. @andrej Authenthication can't be the issue, because I can load tiles in a browser without problems.

Comment: @kay I managed to get the tiles into Openlayers 2 outside QGIS, but I have no clue why it does not work with Quickmapservices or the TileLayer plugin.

Comment: @AndreJ thx for trying!